# GetChildView not called for lastItem (ExpandableList with webView)

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

`getChildView` is not be called for last item !!! , for rest of the items it working fine . (In most of my case i will have 2 parents and with each parent having one child) .

```
public class PDPContentAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> groupList;
    private List<List<String>> childList;
    private boolean isTSV;

    public PDPContentAdapter(Context context, List<String> groupList, List<List<String>> childList, boolean isTSV) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groupList = groupList;
        this.childList = childList;
        this.isTSV = isTSV;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return ((List<String>)childList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String content = ((List<String>) childList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
        Log.e("PDPContent Adapater", groupPosition +"-------"+childPosition);




            WebView webView = new WebView(context);
            webView.loadData("Hello", "text/html",null);        
            return webView;

    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return childList.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groupList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groupList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView view = new TextView(context);
        if(isExpanded)
            view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.pdp_collapse, 0);
        else
            view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.pdp_expand, 0);
        view.setText(groupList.get(groupPosition));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are returning null from `getChild()` and `getGroup()`

Comment: Added impl for these two method , still not working any more suggestions

Comment: try changing it from null to the actual object that needs to be returned. and also return true in isChildSelectable method.

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille : Now getChildView is called in call the cases but webView is not showing contents in few of the cases .

Comment: try logging as to why exactly webview is not shown in some of the cases, when it shows in some. It could be that its not getting the url or data.

Comment: I did that ..and u can see that i am loading static data as if now . What i have realised is that if there is some space at the end of expandableListView , in that case it is able to show data .So i have added a dummy footer and it working now .. Any idea y ?

Comment: i have no idea why on adding a footer it is displayed. may be there could be an issue with the layout, and theres another view that overlaps the expandable listview. but anyways glad that the child view issue is solved.

Comment: Ya , but i need to know the reason  . Anyways Thanks to u and Emmanuel . I will close this thread soon .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my problem is i have added a dummy footer to my expandableListView . Don't know the reason but after that it working fine .

Comment: also add that null should not be returned from the getChild and getGroup method, just so that users get full solutions. :)